# LookAt in Unity 2D is not working correctly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation

I've seen a lot of solutions to this issue and I've tried a lot with no success with any of them. `LookAt` is not working in Unity 2d and Ive been trying for a while.

```
public Transform target; 

// ...

void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
  if (other.gameObject.name.Contains("Anti"))
  {
    Quaternion rot = transform.rotation;
    transform.rotation = rot;
    float z = rot.eulerAngles.z;

    Vector3 pos = transform.position;
    Vector3 velocity = new Vector3(0, -3, 0);

    z += Random.Range(-15.0f, 15.0f);

    rot = Quaternion.Euler( 0, 0, z );

    transform.position = pos;
    transform.rotation = rot;

    maxSpeed = Random.Range(5.0f, 15.0f);
  }
}
```

I am struggling getting anything to work regarding `LookAt` toward my Center doesn't seem to work.

All my other code works (although it has a lot of unnecessary parts I can trim down), its just right before I set Z to a random range, I need it to look at the Origin or Center Object. I cant get that to work at all.

I found a Solution to my issue, I just cleaned out my code and add in

```
     Vector3 diff = Vector3.zero - transform.position;
     diff.Normalize();

     float rot_z = Mathf.Atan2(diff.y, diff.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
     transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, rot_z - 90);
```

I think my issue was the rest of my code,

Comment: Hi @AuatsuriEXE, any chance you could trim this question down to just the minimum amount of code necessary to reproduce the problem?  Also, can you clarify what you mean by "doesn't seem to work"?  ie, does the game object move in the wrong direction, not move at all, etc?  Thanks!

Comment: Yeah ok so, All I need it to do is be able to look at the origin/ or Center Object (All that extra code works, its just whats in gray is what I'm trying to add to it to make it Turn to face the center). before i had it   z += 180 + Random.Range(-15.0f, 15.0f); to simulate artificial bouncing, but now i want it to work like   Face Center Origin > z += Random.Range(-15.0f, 15.0f);.

I just need some code that will work here that will allow me to turn the object to face the center instantly. The ones in gray above are methods i tried out but never worked.

Comment: _is not working_ tells us nothing.  _How_ is it not working?  What do you expect to happen and what _actually_ happens?  What values for the variables did you see when you debugged the code?  Did those values match your expectations?

Comment: So for example, lets say the object is directly behind the origin facing completely away from the origin. LookAt SHOULD make it to where it begins to look at the Origin. That is not happening. I expected the Rotation Values to face towards the center, but they never did. All the methods (those in gray and more) i tried with LookAt or anything regarding looking towards the Origin have all resulted in the same way. The code works fine, its just the methods I am testing don't seem to yield the results at all, its like they don't exist (And i don't mean because they are put under a //)

Comment: what's this for!?
Quaternion rot = transform.rotation;
transform.rotation = rot;
and this
Vector3 pos = transform.position;
transform.position = pos;

You are getting and settign stuff without actually changing it at all. Did you mean to use other.transform.rotation or position perhaps?

Comment: You should re-edit your question and include the commented code that isn't working...as uncommented code. Paul Roub helpfully removed all the commented code because it wasn't needed to explain your problem (except that...some of it *was* important).

Comment: Are you sure that LookAt() is not working? Perhaps your forward direction is just a different direction than the one you want. `transform.LookAt(Vector3.zero)` should always work; then you can use
`transform.Rotate(...)` to add the rotation about the z-axis.